# Magento 2: Maintenance Mode

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, maintenance, redirect-url

I've configured Magento 2 website as maintenance mode from `.maintenance.flag` it's working, at the same time I have configured released IPs from `.maintenance.ip` file.

For multiple IPs not working while for single IP it's working fine.

How can I configure to release selected multiple IPs?

For this I have written I have created.

1) `.maintenance.flag` file from `var`.

2) `.maintenance.ip` file from `var` and written code for release single IP

```
192.168.0.52
```

For single I have written above it's working.

```
192.168.0.52,192.168.0.53
```

For multiple, I have written above it's not working.

Can you please let me know how can I write to release multiple IP's and also how can I configure to redirect particular page while maintenance Mode?

Comment: I love this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For activating maintenance mode with IP addresses execute below command in `CLI`

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip="192.168.0.52" --ip="192.168.0.86"
```

the above command will automatically create a `.maintenance.flag` and `.maintenance.ip` file under `root/var` folder.

and `.maintenance.ip` the file contains the above two IP addresses separated by a comma.

For more Information, you can find from [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html).

*The above information is for maintenance mode*.

To redirect a **custom page** while maintenance mode writes below code in `root/index.php`.

```
$maintenanceFile =  __DIR__ . '/var/.maintenance.flag';

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile)) {
    header('Location: http://127.0.0.1/m2ee/Error.php');
    die();
}
```

**If anyone has better approach please update this answer.**

Answer (score 2):

The Maintenance Mode check-in `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php`.
This file calls to `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/MaintenanceMode.php`. If `.maintenance.flag` file exists in `var` folder, it returns false.

If you want the redirect to a new page when maintenance enables, you need change `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php` file. Add this code below after line 288:

```
header('Location: http://127.0.0.1'); //your page
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to design your maintenance page you need to edit file pub/errors/default/503.phtml and for css pub/errors/default/css/styles.css design accordingly.

And in .htaccess page need to comment ##  SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer or production for execute this maintenance page.

and if you are in production mode then this page will excute other then below code error will show.

```
Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled. 
#0 /backup/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->assertMaintenance()
#1 /backup/html/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#2 {main}
```

if you want to come back in your website you need to delete var/.maintenance file or run below command in terminal

```
//For run your website back online.
php bin/magento maintenance:disable  
//For on maintenance mode.
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

Also set in .htaccess
SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer

follow up my youtube and block

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UChb7DM9SspzrUVh4hnWL50A

https://php-scripts-form.blogspot.com/